# Getting numbers based on list of other numbers in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave

When I type in **(1:4:16)** in matlab / octave
I get **1,5,9,13** as the answer

Is there a way I can get the missing numbers instead?

```
so instead of getting 1,5,9,13 
I get 2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,14,15,16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function:

```
function num = getTheMissingNumbers( from, jump, to )

num = from:to;
num = setdiff( num, from:jump:to );
```

You can call this function

```
>> getTheMissingNumbers( 1, 4, 16 )
```

to get the numbers you want.

---

If you further assume the input to `getThemissingNumbers` always starts with 1, you can implement it even more efficiently using

```
function num = getTheMissingNumbers( jump, to )

num = 1:to;
num(1:jump:to) = []; % remove the elements in ind
```

**EDITED** according to comment by [tmpearce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136302/getting-numbers-based-on-list-of-other-numbers-in-matlab-octave/17136321#comment24799860_17136321).

Comment: That won't get all the way to 16 unfortunately (if that's what the OP wants).